# Calling registerReceiver from a DialogFragment

Tags: android, fragment, receiver

**EDIT**

I added this line:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){...}, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

There is now a runtime error though, the error reads:

**09-03 04:12:41.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'button_send'**

My question would be: Why would it be looking for the method in **android.view.ContextThemeWrapper**?

The button is created on the layout we referenced on line:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_composer, container);
```

and the "button_send" has an onClick method set as:

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

Which is later defined as:

```
public void sendMessage (View v) {
        String phoneNumber = number_input.getText().toString();
        String message = body_input.getText().toString();

        if(message.length() > 0) {              
            sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
            }

        sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
        clearForm();
    }
```

The runtime error happens when the button to send the message is clicked.

**END OF EDIT**

**EDIT Number Two**

Apparently you cannot define the onClick method inside your XML since the button is part of the fragment. In this case, I had to set an onClickListener

Issue FIXED, thanks!

So I am trying to create a DialogFragment that simply sends a new text message. The Dialog has two EditText views, one for the phone number, and one for the actual message; it also has 1 ImageButton that has an onClick method called sendMessage (View v). With that said, I am having issues registering a receiver to catch the result code when the message is being sent. The error message is:

"The method registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){}, IntentFilter) is undefined for the type ComposerDialog"

With exactly the same blocks of code, excepting onCreateView(), I can make this work on an Activity, but apparently not on a **DialogFragment**. My guess is that on the line:

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);
```

by calling getActivity(), I am passing a Dialog as the **context**, and apparently that is not a parameter the call to registerReceiver recognizes on line:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){...}, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

I am thinking of how to change the context I pass to the registerReceiver call, but I am not even sure that is actually the problem. Any ideas?

Here is the full Class for a better perspective:

```
package com.deadpixels.test.sms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ComposerDialog extends DialogFragment {

public ComposerDialog () {
}

private EditText body_input;
private EditText number_input;
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
private static final String TAG = "Composer";

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_composer, container);
        body_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_input);
        number_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_address);
        getDialog().setTitle("Create your new Message!");

        return view;
    }

   private void clearForm() {
        body_input.setText("");
        number_input.setText("");
    }

   public void sendMessage (View v) {
        String phoneNumber = number_input.getText().toString();
        String message = body_input.getText().toString();

        if(message.length() > 0) {              
            sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
            }

        sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
        clearForm();
    }

   private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {           

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

         registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.v(TAG, "SMS sent succesfully");                     
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Log.v(TAG, "Generic failure");
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Log.v(TAG, "No service");                        
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Log.v(TAG, "Null PDU");
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Log.v(TAG, "Radio off");                       
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        smsMgr.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);      
        clearForm();        
    }
```

}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){...}, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

`registerReceiver` is a method of Context which is not present in DialogFragment

Comment: That actually worked, can you explain what happened please? :)

Comment: like I said the method is present in context which is extended by Activity and but is not present in DialogFragment. So you need to get instance of context which you can get through getActivity

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice the Edit :P

Comment: Also - please mind that Fragment does not extend Context, so obviously you can not supply it to methods as a Context parameter.

Comment: @Nandeesh Can you please tell me where to register this receiver like in activity we do it in onResume()?

Comment: @ZohraKhan Fragment also has onresume, so you can register thr

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUiState();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(progressReceiver,new IntentFilter(EPackDownloader.ACTION_PROGRESS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(progressReceiver);
    }
```

and send broadcast like. This is send from AsyncTask having Application context

```
private void updateProgress() {
    //publish progress
    int progress = 100*(totalImageCount - (products.size() * 3 - (3 - (int)downLatch.getCount())))/totalImageCount;
    publishProgress(progress);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    Intent data = new Intent(ACTION_PROGRESS);
    data.putExtra("progress",values[0]);
    data.putExtra("ePackId",ePackModel.id);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(data);
}
```